# Multivalued attribute year in relational database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database, multivalue

The usual way of implementing a multivalued attribute in a relational database is to put it in a separate table with the primary key (maintable_id, multivalued). I have the multivalued attribute `Year`. Following the rule, I create a new table `year` which has the primary key of the main table combined with `year` as an identifier.

It works but doesn't feel right as I have to save a year redundantly, even though it is just a limited amount of years (e.g. 2020 would be saved separately many times for each occurrence of the main table). Is there a better way to model that?

Comment: The question lacks sufficient details. Which version of PostgreSQL? What are the use cases? There are many options for modeling associated years. As mentioned in the original post, a separate table can be used. Arrays, JSON or JSONB, ranges, and multi-ranges are other options. Important considerations are: selectivity of years as part of search criteria; frequency of year as a seach criterion; and whether years are discrete values, single contiguous ranges, or multiple disjoint ranges.

Comment: your answer just give me a lot of hints of thing i didn't think of, thank you. 

i didn't know that you can use array in Postgres in newer versions (from 11). now it makes everything easier. 

the use case was to save information about courses and the years they were offered in.